# Probability Interval for a CCDF Plot in R

Tags: r, probability, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a CCDF plot in R for the whole probability exceedance (from 0-1).
I want to see just the results of a probability interval from 10^(-3) to 10^(-8).
How can I implement this?

My code:

```
# data
n01 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 27947623, sd = 575.839)
ecdf_n01 <- ecdf(n01)

# cumulative cdf
ccdf <- data.frame(x = sort(n01),
                   y = 1-ecdf_n01(sort(n01)))
# plot
plot(ccdf)
x <- sort(n01)
y <- mean(n01)/x
lines(x, y, col="red")
```

Comment: Already tried `plot(ccdf, ylim=c(1e-8, 1e-3))`?

Comment: I had tried this before but my data was not appearing. I just found out that I needed to change then to logscale. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Consider to write an answer yourself. Cheers!